# TypeScript error will not satisfy

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx, typescript-2.5

I'm using TypeScript 2.5.2.
I have tried downgrading to TypeScript 2.2.2, which the same code has worked on another project.

**Error:
file: Weather.tsx'
severity: 'Error'
message: 
'Argument of type '(response: IListItem) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'(value: { weather: IListItem; }) => void | PromiseLike'.
  Types of parameters 'response' and 'value' are incompatible.

Type '{ weather: IListItem; }' has no properties in common with type 'IListItem'.'**

What is wrong with the syntax?

Source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/CodeHeight/some-webparts)

[image: VSCode Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From just looking at these types and not the rest of the code: the type parameter in `.then((response: HttpClientResponse): Promise<{weather: IListItem}>` specifies that the response is an object with a `weather` property of type `IListItem` rather than the bare `IListItem` you expect at `.then((response: IListItem): void => {`, which explains the type error.

If the api response is indeed an object, you can change the latter to `.then((response: {weather: IListItem})` and add `.weather` to each appearance of `response` in the body (or even simply destructure without a type annotation: `then(({weather}): void => {` and use `weather` instead of `response`.)

On the other hand, if the api just returns an `IListItem`, you can change the former to `.then((response: HttpClientResponse): Promise<IListItem> => {`.

Comment: .then((response: HttpClientResponse): Promise<IListItem> was my solution.  Thank you sir.

Comment: similar issue with promises.  Do you know what the error could be?:  https://github.com/CodeHeight/some-webparts/issues/1

Comment: If you post it as an SO question other people can also have a go at it :-)

Comment: you're right, it's a separate question.  Eventually, got the syntax to work with <any>.   The different TypeScript versions are killing me.  ;-0